# Create a filter category option select with vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to creat this filter category with vuejS. Even though the code seems correct It doesn't behave as expected.Below is the code or you can directly review it at https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-js-template-wfxhec?file=index.js

**HTML**

```html
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option v-on:click="setFilter('ALL')" >ALL</option>   
    <option v-on:click="setFilter('WEB DEVELOPMENT')"selected="selected">Web development</option>
    <option v-on:click="setFilter('Design')">Design</option>
    <option v-on:click="setFilter('WORDPRESS DEVELOPMENT')">Wordpress DEVELOPMENT</option>
    <option v-on:click="setFilter('Design')">FREE COURSES</option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

**VUEJS**

```
import './style.css';
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentFilter: 'ALL',
        projects: [
            {title: "Web development", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=116", category: 'WEB DEVELOPMENT'},
            {title: "WEB UX/UI DESIGN", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=121", category: 'Design'},
            {title: "Wordpress", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=133", category: 'WORDPRESS DEVELOPMENT'},
        {title: "Design", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=121", category: 'FREE COURSE'}, 
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        setFilter: function(filter) {
            this.currentFilter = filter;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **v-model** on the select field then make sure the text between the  matches the name of each category in the objects then you can set you currentFilter value to ALL by default and when you change the option it will update the currentFilter since you used v-model two way binding and you can do some if check before displaying the courses you can check if the course category matches the current filter of if the currentFilter is === to All then you will display all the courses.

```js
    new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                currentFilter: 'ALL',
                projects: [
                    {title: 'Web development', image:               './images/camping.jpg', category: 'WEB DEVELOPMENT' },
                    {title: 'WEB UX/UI DESIGN', image: './images/grid1jpg', category: 'Design' },
                    {title: 'Wordpress', image: './images/grid2.jpg', category: 'WORDPRESS DEVELOPMENT' },
                    {title: 'Design', image: './images/health6.jpeg', category: 'FREE COURSE' }
                ]
            },
        })
```

```html
 <div id="app">
    <h1>Filter the bello list</h1>
    <select tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" v-model="currentFilter">
        <option>ALL</option>   
        <option>WEB DEVELOPMENT</option>
        <option>Design</option>
        <option>WORDPRESS DEVELOPMENT</option>
        <option>FREE COURSE</option>
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <h2>List of courses </h2>
    <div>
        <ul v-for="course in projects" v-if="course.category === currentFilter || currentFilter === 'ALL'">
            <li>{{ course.title }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That should work just find

Answer (score 1):

Use the `v-model` property to bind your `select` to a list of `projectTypes` then the filter will be automatically updated on change.

**MARKUP**

```html
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" v-model="currentFilter">
    <option  v-for="project in projectTypes" :value="project" :key="project">{{ project }}</option>
</select>
```

**JS***

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentFilter: 'ALL',
        projectTypes: [
           'ALL',
           'WEB DEVELOPMENT',
           'Design',
           'WORDPRESS DEVELOPMENT',
           'FREE COURSE'
        ],
        projects: [
            {title: "Web development", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=116", category: 'WEB DEVELOPMENT'},
            {title: "WEB UX/UI DESIGN", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=121", category: 'Design'},
            {title: "Wordpress", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=133", category: 'WORDPRESS DEVELOPMENT'},
            {title: "Design", image: "https://picsum.photos/g/200?image=121", category: 'FREE COURSE'}, 
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: it doesnt work actually...any update on why? When I add the code the entire page becomes white no more content is showing

Comment: If you update your stackblitz example I can try and help, but it should work.

Comment: I did update my example, you can check on the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-js-template-wfxhec?file=index.js